# Detect user selection in Location Access Popup Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I have a view controller that takes the user location and shows the shops nearby.

When the user opens the app for the first time, the app shows a popup for the user to allow location access. If the user allows location, I call the API in `didUpdateLocations`

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if !isNearbyAlreadyLoaded {
        self.apiNearbyBakers()
        isNearbyAlreadyLoaded = true
    }
}
```

But if the user doesn't allow the location, my API is never called. In that condition, I need to show him a button to allow location.

**Question**:

How can I detect if the user has tapped **Don't Allow** button in the **Allow location popup.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `didChangeAuthorization` callback method. This method is called when the user selects an option from the popup.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedAlways {
        if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
            if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
    if status == .denied {
        // handle your case
    }
}
```

There is a complete article about this [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/22/2/requesting-location-core-location)

Answer (score 1):

Create a extension for CLLocationManagerDelegate
then check for status and perform your funcationality accordingly, if permission is not set then open settings.

```
extension HomeVC: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        guard status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse else {
            if status == .denied || status == .notDetermined || status == .restricted || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message:"Some Descriptions" , preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                    let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            return
        }
    }
}
```